# Get grouped value divided by total

Tags: postgresql, group-by, resultset

I have a table like this :

```
+----+---------------+----------+
| id | city          | price    |
+----±---------------±----------+
| 1  | Paris         | 2.000,00 |
| 2  | London        | 500,00   |
| 3  | Paris         | 500,00   |
| 4  | Madrid        | 1.000,00 |
±----±---------------±----------±
```

And a request like this :

```
select
    city,
    sum(price)
from orders
group by city
order by sum(price) desc
```

This gives me a result like :

```
+----------+---------------+
| city     | SUM(price)    |
+----------±---------------±
| Paris    | 2.500,00      |
| Madrid   | 1.000,00      |
| London   | 500,00        |
±----------±---------------±
```

What I would like to have is the ratio of the price for each city in a third column, so that Paris would have 62.50 % and so on, like this :

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| city     | SUM(price)    | Ratio       |
+----------±---------------±-------------+
| Paris    | 2.500,00      | 62,50       |
| Madrid   | 1.000,00      | 25          |
| London   | 500,00        | 12,50       |
±----------±---------------±-------------±
```

Currently, I have to calculate the last column in PHP after getting the first resultset. I was wondering if there was any way I could do this directly in SQL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest doing with a CTE to improve reading, but you will get same performance as Giorgios answer.

```
WITH cte0 as (
     SELECT *
     FROM Orders
     WHERE <filters>
),
cte as (
     SELECT SUM(price) total
     FROM cte0 
)
SELECT city, sum(price), 100.0 * SUM(Price) /  cte.total
FROM cte0 
CROSS JOIN cte
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: With PostgreSQL, you will have to modify the `GROUP BY` to `city, cte.total`. This solution works indeed, but it will make me repeat my whole filters into the `WITH` select part.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean. Maybe you should include a more detail description of your problem

Comment: But if you are adding filter you can add another `cte0` before to filter and use it for `cte` and final query

Comment: As I said to Giorgos Betsos in his answer, I have many where-clauses to my actual query that I didn't paste here for readability purpose. It's not really a problem, it's juste that it will build a huge request with that solution. That's why I mentioned `window function` in a comment below.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you can add another `cte0`" ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: I try window function but dont see how do that, because you also need a group by. So are two different things and cant be calculated together. I update my answer to reflect the `cte0` but again, if your problem is more complicated just improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the total price:

```
select
    city,
    sum(price),
    100.0 * sum(price) / (select sum(price) from Orders) AS Ratio
from Orders
group by city
order by sum(price) desc
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daa93/2)

Alternatively you can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select
    city,
    sum(price),
    100.0 * sum(price) / t.total_price AS Ratio
from Orders
cross join (select sum(price) as total_price from Orders) AS t
group by city
order by sum(price) desc
```

Comment: probably better multiply for `100.0` to get decimals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a query a bit more complicated than this one actually. I knew it was possible with sub-queries but I was wondering if there was a "better" way of doing it (probably window function ?)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, that's correct, thank you very much.